# Ergodic properties of orthogonal group $O(n)$

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, ergodic-theory, orthogonality

The orthogonal group $O(n)$ is the group of distance-preserving transformations of a Euclidean space of dimension n that preserve a fixed point, where the group operation is given by composing transformations.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group

Any references for the ergodic properties of that group acting on the n-sphere?

Thank you

Comment: Please consider accepting some answers for the 104 questions you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Ergodicity is ensured by the fact that the eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix satisfy $\|\lambda_i\|=1$, hence $\lambda_i = e^{i\theta_i}$. By the Dirichlet box principle, it follows that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ there exists $m\in\mathbb{N}_0$, with $m\leq (2\pi n)^n$, such that:
$$\max_{i\in[1,n]}\left\|\frac{m\theta_i}{2\pi}\right\|\leq\frac{1}{n},$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the distance from the closest integer. Ergodicity follows.

Comment: any references, because I need the context for your answer. I am new to this field.

Comment: @D'Aurizio link was empty

Comment: @TKM: http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~peters10/teaching/Spring2011/ErgodicTheoryNotes.pdf